# I18nProvider defined in WAR causes other WARs in web server to crash

Tags: java, internationalization, wildfly, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin 14.5.1 and Wildfly 17. I have several applications deployed in Wildfly. Now I'm implementing internationalization using Vaadin's `I18nProvider` interface.
So I created a `TranslationProvider` class which implements the interface in module A, and as per [this guide](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/i18n/i18nprovider) I activate it using:

`setProperty("vaadin.i18n.provider", TranslationProvider.class.getName());`

After deployment, if I try to go to module B, it gives an error like:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.module.A.TranslationProvider from [Module "deployment.B.war" from Service Module Loader]`

The error is clear, my `TranslationProvider` is in module A, so of course module B can't find it. But the translation provider should be only for module A and nothing else. How should I go about this? Can I "disable" the system property once I exit from my module? Is there a way for other modules just to ignore it?

Comment: The DefaultInstantiator only works with the property.  Do you plan to use Spring - if so you don't need the property. Otherwise I think the "easiest" way would be to inject your own Instantiator impl (derived from DefaultInstantiator where you just overide loading your I18nProvider)

Comment: We've started using Spring recently for future development, but this application in particular will remain without spring for the foreseeable future. I have no knowledge of Instantiator implementations, could you maybe link websites where I can start looking into them?

Comment: I don't think there is some HowTo. You would have to follow the code comments.

Comment: Well isn't that nice? Anyway, thank you for the pointer!